# auditctl doesn't log anything

Tags: linux, rhel, amazon-ec2, linux-audit

I am trying to find app/activity on a server for failed connection to external mysql host.
For that I decided to use `auditctl`. I'm running the following command:

```
[nir]$ sudo auditctl -A exit,always -F arch=b64 -S connect
[nir]$ sudo auditctl -l | grep -i 'arch'
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S connect
[nir]$ sudo ls -l -h /var/log/audit/audit.log
-rw------- 1 root root 6.2M May  1  2020 /var/log/audit/audit.log
[nir]$ sudo auditctl -m 'hey, are you working at all?'
[nir]$ sudo ls -l -h /var/log/audit/audit.log
-rw------- 1 root root 6.2M May  1  2020 /var/log/audit/audit.log
[nir]$ service auditd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status auditd.service
● auditd.service - Security Auditing Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-12-15 20:24:05 UTC; 1 years 2 months ago
     Docs: man:auditd(8)
           https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-documentation
 Main PID: 1898 (auditd)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 140.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/auditd.service
           └─1898 /sbin/auditd

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

But the log file `/var/log/audit/audit.log` does not get updated at all. I'm using aws ec2 server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your command works on my Centos 8 VM. Is your `auditd` running? `/var/log/audit/audit.log`, if it's RHEL or Centos anyway, should be moderately busy, even without auditing. Could it be that the system logger writes audit records to a different file? You can check if auditing works at all by sending a text message `auditctl -m 'hey, are you working at all?'`.

Comment: How can I check the configured audit file ?

Comment: Normally, `auditd` sends its messages to `rsyslogd`, which writes them to files or other destinations. It's configured by `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d/*`.

Comment: nothing written there

Comment: When you send a text message with `auditctl`, does it show up somewhere? I have a Ubuntu 16 server at home. It contains `auth,authpriv.*  /var/log/auth.log` in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`. You need to figure out where audit logs are written.